# Absolute positioned div floats over main content

Tags: html, css

I am absolutely positioning a footer at the bottom of the browser window, using the following code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            Content
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: red;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
```

This works just as intended, however when I make the browser window smaller the footer will eventually cover the main content. What is the most efficient way of preventing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why must you use absolute positioning for your footer?

Comment: @mc10 I'm using absolute positioning as I want the footer to 'stick' to the bottom of the browser window.

Comment: How about adding a `z-index` to your `#content`?

Comment: @mc10 As far as I'm aware, that will mean the footer will then disappear behind the content. This is not what I'm after, I wish for it to just stop moving when they 'meet'.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Afs6/7/)

Here is [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Afs6/8/) using pseudo-elements. You may have some issues with old versions of IE, but it allows you to forgo un-semantic elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#content {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: red;
}

#footer {
    position:fixed; //Changed to fixed
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 20px;
}
```